# REST API for Sharepoint to get subsite users

Tags: rest, sharepoint

All I want to do is get a list of users **allowed to access a specific *subsite*** in SharePoint using the **REST API** only. Just a single HTTP GET like such:

`http://<site url>/_api/Web/SiteUsers`

Yes, I know that the above referenced call will give me ALL USERS allowed to access ANY SharePoint site and that is not what I want or need, it is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve subsite users the following endpoint could be utilized:

```
Url: /_api/web/roleAssignments/groups
Method: Get
```

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve web groups along with a users and then extract the users:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/roleAssignments/groups?$expand=Users";
$.getJSON(url)
.then(function(data){

    var webUsers = [];

    //extract users from groups
    data.value.forEach(function(g){
         if(g.Users.length > 0)
            webUsers = webUsers.concat(g.Users);
    }); 


    console.log(webUsers);

});
```

Comment: Once I add the $expand=Users option, all I get is a Login box (to which I cannot successfully login). I can run the query just fine without the $expand option. And ideas?

Comment: @BrianP., hmm, it seems you dont have sufficient permissions to enumerate users & groups

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, but it took a while to 1) get permissions and 2) collect the data. Now that I've run the query as suggested, I have to say that the result is ALL users on the SharePoint site in general not the ones with permission on the subsite. Therefore, I cannot say that this question is answered.

Comment: @BrianP. i guess your query is executed against root site, e.g.  `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/roleAssignments/groups`, in that case it is expected result, all users are getting returned.  To retrieve user from _sub web_,  **sub site url** needs to be specified in service url  e.g.  `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/projectsite/_api/web/roleAssignments/groups`

Comment: I am running the query against the subsite (specifically https://contosco.sharepoint.com/subsite/subsubsite/_api ...)